# error in installing statsmodels for python 3.6.1

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to install the statistics model in Python 3.6.1, but I get the following exception error.

Does anyone have any idea what it can be?

I have installed Visual C++. I do not know if I should install something else.

```
 Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Sebastián>cd C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36>cd Scripts

C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip install statsmodels
Collecting statsmodels
  Using cached statsmodels-0.8.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: statsmodels
  Running setup.py install for statsmodels ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 148: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\sebastián\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 148: invalid continuation byte

C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>
```

Comment: the error message sounds like you're trying to open a file and decode it as utf-8, when it isn't utf-8 (either it's not a valid encoding, or it's in some other encoding). Not sure what that would have to do with installing C++ (especially since you're using Python).

Comment: Have you tried updating pip to its latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you installed "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).  According to this (https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) you need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 which is in either Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.  I used Visual Studio Community 2015 with the install option "Programming Languages\Visual C++\Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" and got it to install